# Get-ADObject for DNS A-Record

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

how do I get the ADObject for a DNS A Record?

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name server1 -ZoneName Zone1.biz | Get-ADObject
```

does not work. I am just able to do this with "guessing" the DN.

```
Get-ADObject -Identity "DC=server1,dc=zone1.biz,cn=MicrosoftDns,dc=DomainDnsZones,dc=domain,dc=biz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the output object of [Get-DnsServerResourceRecord](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/3a5072bd-150f-4ca3-ab96-6ef007b4f49e(v=wps.630).aspx) is [DnsServerResourceRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh832775.aspx). From which you could pass the distinguished name into the [Get-ADObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/fbc1d06f-c845-4b26-8ae2-dca1b8e53107(v=wps.630).aspx) as it takes Identity as position 1 and can accept distinguishedname as an identity.

This is untested, but try this:

```
(Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name server1 -ZoneName Zone1.biz).DistinguishedName | Get-ADObject
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you get from the Get-DnsServerResourceRecord will mostlikely need to be filtered to pipe it.
Also, what kind of details do you need from the ADObject? Can get-adcomputer get the same data?
This one works fine for me :

```
(Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name server1 -ZoneName Zone1.biz).hostname | Get-ADComputer
```

Comment: Most of our DNS records don't have computer objects. Thanks